# Plinq in a single core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, plinq

As far as I understand:

> Programming to leverage multicores or multiple processors is called
>   parallel programming.

But what about If I *don't* have >1 cores ?

Does a command  like:

```
"abcdef".AsParallel().Select(c=>char.ToUpper(c)).ToArray()
```

will be running *sequentially* ?

(I know that even if I have >1 cores , Plinq optimization still can choose *not* to parallel. But My question is about having ==1 cores.)

**Or**

It still can be in *multiple* threads (1 core) like :

[image]

*(but IMHO it wont be parallel programming)*

I'm a bit confused.any Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PLinq will default the allowed degree of parallelism to
*Math.Min(ProcessorCount, MAX_SUPPORTED_DOP) where MAX_SUPPORTED_DOP is* 
64 for .NET 4.0 and 512 for .NET 4.6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383719.aspx)

You may explicitly raise the max concurrency limit beyond that (or lower it below that), and that leaves PLinq the freedom to use from 1 to <limit> threads to do your work. Usually raising the defaults is only useful if your work is heavily I/O bound.

In other words, unless you change the default concurrency limits using for example  [WithDegreeOfParallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383719.aspx), your tasks will run using a single thread on a single core.

Comment: If I have 3 long calculations , the sum of the execution timeof all 3 will be the same in a multithreaded env or single threaded , its just a quanta being given to each thread each time .....right ?

Comment: I know this command `WithDegreeOfParallelism` which is for blocking issues  like 5 web services at once ( which is not CPU intensive but blocking)

Comment: WithDegreeOfParallelism  is  also for a situation which i have 8 cores butI want only 2 to be used with parallel...

Comment: Sorry :-) But I dont see How your answer , answers my question ...:-)

Comment: @RoyiNamir With 1 core, PLinq's default is to use a maximum concurrency of 1, that is, it will run the Linq query sequentially.

Comment: @RoyiNamir No, it will not create extra threads when the concurrency limit is set to 1.

Comment: Thanks. One more thing. There is a different if 2 threads on the same core vs 2 threads in different cores right ?

Comment: And what is MAX_SUPPORTED_DOP ?

Comment: MAX_SUPPORTED_DOP is hard coded to 64, that is, even if you have more than 64 cores, you will only get a default concurrency of 64.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15225/discussion-between-royi-namir-and-joachim-isaksson)